# symfony form builder across a one-to-many to a many-to-one

Tags: symfony, one-to-many, symfony-forms, many-to-one

I know this is possible but I'm lost on where to start. My main trouble is figuring out how to set up the form classes.

My Entities:

> Formula (id, code, name, formulaColors)
>
> FormulaColor (formula, color, percentage)
>
> Color (id, code, name, formulaColors)

I want to display a multiple-choice checklist for a given formula that displays every color in a table grid. The grid will have a column that displays the code, the name, and a checkbox for each color. These are probably not the important details though. The user should be able to check the boxes and on submit and persist it should add the check ones to Formula->formulaColors, ultimately adding it to the FormulaColor table. Also, colors that already belong to a formula should already be checked when the form is built. I think this would be easier for me had `FormulaColor` table been a true join table without the percentage field.

In the controller action, I have access to the formula that needs to have the colors chosen for it.

What would my form classes look like, at least roughly speaking?

My form class:

```
class ChooseColorsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('formulaColors', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrismPortalCommonBundle:Color',
                'property' => 'code',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Formula'
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'prism_portal_adminbundle_choosecolorstype';
    }
}
```

However, this gives me the exception

> Error: Call to undefined method
> Prism\Portal\CommonBundle\Entity\Color::getPercentage() in
> /vagrant/src/Prism/Portal/CommonBundle/Entity/Formula.php line 201

I'm guessing this has to do with it being not a regular `many-to-many` relationship. I don't know how to address this `getPercentage()` exception

**Update**

I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet but I will tomorrow. I think this may be the answer to my problem: http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

I didn't think of adding a mutator and accessor to my Formula entity for dealing with a Color directly.

Comment: Did the link, you provided above, help you? @user45763